# Using 2 returned lists as inputs for another method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate the values of 2 variables in one method and then return them. Then use the returned values as inputs for another method which graphically displays them - the variables contain lists. I could not find any relevant information to solve this problem. Further elaboration below code snippet follows.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np  #importing numpy for optimised arrays
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # importing module to graphically display arrays 

class Mandelbrot(object):  #creating class to generate a mandelbrot set
    def __init__(self,x1,x2,y1,y2,iterations,axis_points):  #initialising the relevant parameters
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.axis_points = axis_points
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2

    def parameters(self):  #creating method to generate a list of evenly spaced numbers to create a 2D grid, 
        xrange = np.linspace(self.x1,self.x2,self.axis_points)  #then only storing numbers which are part of the mandelbrot set
        yrange = np.linspace(self.y1,self.y2,self.axis_points)
        count = 0
        counts = []
        full_grid = []
        for i in xrange:  #looping over every coordinate in the created grid to test if it is in the mandelbrot set
            for j in yrange:
                count = 0
                z = complex(0.0,0.0)  #initialising complex number to hold the iterations inside the while loop
                z_mag = 0
                full_grid.append((complex(i,j)))
                while z_mag <= 2:  #iterating until "point-of-no-return" thershold
                    z_mag = np.linalg.norm(z)  #optimised function to return the magnitude of the complex number
                    z =z**2 + complex(i,j)  #updating values of complex number 
                    count+=1
                    if z_mag > 2: 
                        counts.append(count)
                    elif count > 255:  #only adding to mandelbrot set if the number can pass a set number of iterations
                        counts.append(256)
                        break  #ending while loop to go to new coordinate on grid
        np_full_grid = np.array(full_grid)                
        return np_full_grid,counts

    def display(self):  #creating method to graphically display mandelbrot set       
        f, ax = plt.subplots()
        points = ax.scatter(self.real, self.imag, c=counts, s=1, cmap="prism")  #displaying filtered grid
        f.colorbar(points)  #generating colour bar from
```

Here is my test code:

```
def main():
    M = Mandelbrot(-2.025,0.6,-1.125,1.125,255,200)  #setting parameters for the iteration
    generated_set = Mandelbrot.parameters(M)  #storing the list of mandelbrot set coordinates in complex plane
    Mandelbrot.display(generated_set)  #graphically displaying the generated mandelbrot set 
main()
```

When returning np_full_grid only and using it for the display method its all working, but I also need access to the counts list in order to correctly plot. But when I return np_full_grid and counts it becomes a tuple and the self. does not work anymore, how can I have access to both of the returned values to be used in the display method? thanks

Comment: This question is very confusing, because you've quoted some code, but left out most of the most important bits. We don't need to see how you're calculating your `np_full_grid` and `count` values, since you're question isn't about that calculation. But what we do need to see is where you're calling `parameters` from, and what you're attempting to do with the return values. It's also not very clear where the functions you show are written. Are they methods of some class (I'd guess yes from the `self` argument, but I have no idea what the class is).

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry, I have now provided all of the code that is relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but if youwant to return multiple variables you can do:

```
def foo():
    return a, b

c, d = foo()
```

Based on the sample code you gave, you're calling the function incorrectly. Try this:

```
def main():
    M = Mandelbrot(-2.025,0.6,-1.125,1.125,255,200)  
    #setting parameters for the iteration
    generated_set, counts = M.parameters()  #storing  the list of mandelbrot set coordinates in complex plane
    M.display(generated_set)  #graphically 
displaying the generated mandelbrot set 

main()
```

The reason is that `M` is an instance of the Mendelbrot class. You don't pass M to the function, you use it to call it instead.

Comment: I want to store the returned values in a variable and then feed that variable into the display method

Comment: @Σbaryon I've added an example for your specific problem

Comment: Took me a while, but the problem seemed to be my lack of knowledge that I could set  variables "generated_set" and "counts" at the same time. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although I have accepted an answer, I think this code is in a more OOP style

The code for the display method should be:

```
def display(np_full_grid,counts):  #creating method to graphically display mandelbrot set       
        f, ax = plt.subplots()
        points = ax.scatter(np_full_grid.real, np_full_grid.imag, c=counts, s=1, cmap="viridis")  #displaying filtered grid
        f.colorbar(points)  #generating colour bar from
```

The test code should be:

```
def main():
    M = Mandelbrot(-2.025,0.6,-1.125,1.125,255,100)  #setting parameters for the iteration
    generated_set,counts = Mandelbrot.parameters(M)  #storing the list of mandelbrot set coordinates in complex plane and their corresponding count
    Mandelbrot.display(generated_set,counts)  #graphically displaying the generated mandelbrot set 
main()
```

Comment: Note that while this may be what makes your code work, it's deeply weird to be passing a non-instance to a method as `self`. I'd suggest learning more about Python OOP, as code like this will confuse the hell out of anybody else who reads it, even if it works.

Comment: @Blckknght I have changed the name of the variable now to "np_full_grid" - the same as the returned variable name